# Unable to access my global SE profile

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, profile-page

When I am logged into stackexchange.com, I try clicking on my name at the top bar and I'm taken to a page that directs me to where I might find pandas (Page Not Found) ([link](https://stackexchange.com/users/c8b978b7-d075-4ba1-8afc-8b222b4aff5c)). As a side note, I look to the right of my screen and alas there are no pandas there. Anyway, is clicking on my name supposed to be taking me somewhere else? I can access my SO profile just fine from stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackexchange.com/users/a4ccfa77-0d4d-4862-b292-7de723171aa5) the link it tries to take you to or does it take you somewhere else?

Comment: @Rebecca it tries to take me [here](http://stackexchange.com/users/c8b978b7-d075-4ba1-8afc-8b222b4aff5c). The link you provided seems to be the correct one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a tad subtle.

Basically, sometime in the last week or two your "identity" changed from the Stack Exchange network's perspective.

Why you ask?  Probably because of an OpenId change (I see a number in your recent user history) that led to us picking up an older account in your associated accounts.

StackExchange.com ties your identity *there* to your identity on the oldest account you own.  If the apparent oldest account changes, things can get a bit... odd.  Throw in some caching, and now you're getting directed to a page that doesn't exist anymore.

Anyway, this should now be resolved; the link on StackExchange.com will take you to a page that actually exists.